# sentiment analysis - elastic stack

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, tweepy, sentiment-analysis

I am using the newest version of Elastic stack (Logstash, Elasticsearch, Kibana) to perform some Twitter analysis and I would like to add a sentiment analysis to it (basic one is fine, nothing too complicated) however all options I found were using libraries like tweepy to input data into elasticsearch with sentiment included, however I did not find solution that would allow me to still use the full stack (including logstash). is the analysis have to be done on logstash level, before inputting data into elasticsearch? Is it possible to use tweepy and logstash at the same time somehow?

Thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can with vanilla stack. At best you can write your own ingest processor, or use an existing one.

I know OpenNLP has some classifier which you can write a plugin that utilizes that. Use [this](https://github.com/spinscale/elasticsearch-ingest-opennlp) as an inspiration. Or maybe [this](https://github.com/apanimesh061/elasticsearch-sentiment-plugin)

Comment: thank you very much I checked it out but they both seem to be based on elasticsearch 5.x and Im running 6.2, Im pretty sure its not going to be compatible as it never seems to be... I might experiment with changing logstash to tweepy maybe. I have found this [link](https://github.com/tylerjl/logstash-filter-sentimentalizer) however not sure if that is compatible either.